# TreeView in WPF with multiple columns

Tags: c#, wpf, grid, treeview

[image]

How to achieve this kind of TreeView in wpf?
I started learning WPF not so long ago. But I did not find any specific information on this issue

The maximum result that could be achieved is to create a DockPanel. In it, add a DataGrid with only headers and a Treeview in which to hierarchicaldatatemplate add a Grid. Link the width of the DataGrid header to the Grid inside the TreeView. But when you expand the elements in the TreeView, the elements of the other columns are shifted. Any navigation will help.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read the [How](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to Ask page. StackOverflow is not a site where strangers make your homework. It consists of volunteers that are happy to help - but you need to show what you have tried first.